# CSS: Trying to get a horizontal menu formatted the right way, not consistent accross browsers

Tags: html, css, menu, consistency

I am trying to make a horizontal menu look pretty.
Here's an example of what my HTML looks like.

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a class="selected" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="labs.html">Labs</a></li>
    <li><a href="assignments.html">Assignments</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is a snippet from my CSS.  It does the job in Firefox but not IE.

```
#menu {
margin:auto;
padding-top: 4px;
width: 800px;
}

#menu ul
{
float:left;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-top:7px;
padding-left:20px;
}    

#menu li
{
font: 87.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet Unicode MS", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
display:inline-block;
}

#menu a, #menu a.selected
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
background-color:#fff;
background-image:url('../images/menu-unselected.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
padding-top:4px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-left:12px;
padding-right:12px;
border:solid;
border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
border-color:#000;
}

#menu a.selected
{
padding-top:7px;
padding-bottom:1px;
border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu a.selected
{
background-image:url('');
}
```

I can make changes to the css to get it working right in IE, but then it doesn't work in FireFox!  Here's screenshots of the code above rendered in each browser:

Firefox: [here](http://dhines.com/ff.jpg)

Internet Explorer: [here](http://dhines.com/ie.jpg)

Comment: You'll need to explain (or add a picture of) "the right look" you're going for.

Comment: As Brent said. I put your code in a jsfiddle, yet I'm unsure on what you're wanting to acheive

http://jsfiddle.net/74UsA/

Comment: used display:inline-block on #menu li and got the following results:
FireFox: http://dhines.com/ff.jpg
IE: http://dhines.com/ie.jpg

So now the firefox display is the one I want, while IE is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

On     #menu li instead of     display:inline; replace it with     float:left;

Then on     #menu a.selected use padding and margin to reposition it taller than the others. I added:

```
padding-bottom:4px;
padding-top:7px;
margin-top:5px;
```

display:block; on     #menu a seems optional. I'm on a Mac in FF 7.0.1 and it looks correct. Can't see it in IE. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

i tend to use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;` when it's possible, and never had problems cross-browsers. So what i suggest to you is to use `#menu li{ display:inline-block;}`.

Obviously all changes are relative to your default layout ... wrappers,pages,body,html etc etc ..

Answer (score 0):

Change `display: inline-block;` to  `display: inline;` in your `li`.

Then add `display: block; float: left;` to your `a`.

You would then change the style of the tabs through the `a` tag (things such as `text-align`, `width`, etc).

Comment: Still having issues with those changes.  See screenshots.  IE: http://dhines.com/ie2.jpg
    
    FF: http://dhines.com/ff2.jpg